# Scipy and PIL fail to generate monochrome bitmap file

Tags: python, scipy, python-imaging-library

I'm attempting to generate a monochrome bitmap (uint8 for each pixel) for uploading to an external device as a bytestring.

```
import scipy.misc
import numpy as np

image = np.ones((100,100),dtype=np.uint8)*255
image[0:50] = 0

scipy.misc.imsave('nomode.bmp',image)

im =scipy.misc.toimage(image, mode='1')
im.convert('1').save('mode_1.bmp')
```

the code above generates a blank image (all black) for the correct file size but the correct image in the nomode.bmp

[Mode_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InKGt.png) - File shows 1.62kB (size I want)

[Nomode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSM8b.png) - File shows 10.8kB (Too large)

Am I misunderstanding how to use the mode argument. or is there a better less stupid way to generate a bitmap header and file?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a PIL image from color to bilevel using `Image.convert('1')`.

You could do:

```
im.convert('1').save('monochrome.bmp')
```

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. im.convert('1') gave the same behavior  im.convert('L') as suggested works when looking at the produced bitmaps as images but when read back as a bytearray has multiple bytes per pixel.

Comment: Could you please edit the question to include the code/evidence from which you are basing the conclusion that image is not monochrome?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a mode 'L' image if you want to have an 8-bit value for every pixel:

```
import scipy.misc
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

image = np.ones((684, 608), dtype=np.uint8) * 255
image[300:490, 300:800] = 0
im = scipy.misc.toimage(image, mode="L")
im.save("outfile.bmp", mode="L")
im.show()
```

It is unclear to me for what purpose you need the 'bitmap header'.